# Emulator suddenly stopped working while running an app

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Hi I'm new to android programming

I'm able to run hello world program successful on my emulator but i cant able to run the other programs which im writing from developer.android.com/training

I'm getting the logcat errors which  cant able to understand and I'm searching for the solution since from 2 days

Logcat errors

> 05-06 03:54:23.490: D/dalvikvm(1078): Not late-enabling CheckJNI
>   (already on) 05-06 03:54:26.440: D/gralloc_goldfish(1078): Emulator
>   without GPU emulation detected. 05-06 03:54:31.760:
>   I/Choreographer(1078): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 05-06 03:54:32.190:
>   E/FragmentManager(1078): No view found for id 0x7f05003c
>   (com.vijay.mgit:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{b2e07990 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 05-06 03:54:32.190:
>   E/FragmentManager(1078): Activity state: 05-06 03:54:32.190:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):   Local FragmentActivity b2dfdce8 State:
>   05-06 03:54:32.230: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false 05-06
>   03:54:32.230: D/FragmentManager(1078):     mLoadersStarted=false 05-06
>   03:54:32.230: D/FragmentManager(1078):   Active Fragments in b2dfdf58:
>   05-06 03:54:32.240: D/FragmentManager(1078):     #0:
>   PlaceholderFragment{b2e07990 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 05-06 03:54:32.240:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c
>   mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null 05-06 03:54:32.240:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):       mState=0 mIndex=0
>   mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0 05-06 03:54:32.250:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false
>   mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false 05-06 03:54:32.250:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):       mHidden=false mDetached=false
>   mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false 05-06 03:54:32.250:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false
>   mUserVisibleHint=true 05-06 03:54:32.250: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{b2dfdf58 in
>   DisplayMessageActivity{b2dfdce8}} 05-06 03:54:32.250:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   mActivity=com.vijay.mgit.DisplayMessageActivity@b2dfdce8 05-06
>   03:54:32.260: D/FragmentManager(1078):   Added Fragments: 05-06
>   03:54:32.280: D/FragmentManager(1078):     #0:
>   PlaceholderFragment{b2e07990 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 05-06 03:54:32.310:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):   FragmentManager misc state: 05-06
>   03:54:32.310: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   mActivity=com.vijay.mgit.DisplayMessageActivity@b2dfdce8 05-06
>   03:54:32.310: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@b2dfdfd0 05-06
>   03:54:32.320: D/FragmentManager(1078):     mCurState=2
>   mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false 05-06 03:54:32.320:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):   View Hierarchy: 05-06 03:54:32.320:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2dffce0
>   V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0} 05-06 03:54:32.330: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{b2e003a0 V.ED....
>   ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout} 05-06
>   03:54:32.330: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.FrameLayout{b2e01030 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002
>   android:id/content} 05-06 03:54:32.360: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.TextView{b2dff860 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0} 05-06
>   03:54:32.380: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b2e014b0 V.ED.... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container} 05-06 03:54:32.380:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{b2e01a38 V.E..... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #1020315 android:id/action_bar} 05-06 03:54:32.380:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{b2e02028 VFE...C. ... 0,0-0,0} 05-06
>   03:54:32.390: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{b2e03188 V.E.....
>   ... 0,0-0,0} 05-06 03:54:32.390: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.ImageView{b2e035a0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102025a
>   android:id/up} 05-06 03:54:32.390: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.ImageView{b2e03980 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c
>   android:id/home} 05-06 03:54:32.390: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{b2e04d78 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0} 05-06
>   03:54:32.400: D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.TextView{b2e05110 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020265
>   android:id/action_bar_title} 05-06 03:54:32.400:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   android.widget.TextView{b2e05e18 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020266
>   android:id/action_bar_subtitle} 05-06 03:54:32.400:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{b2e064b8 G.E..... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/action_context_bar} 05-06 03:54:32.400:
>   D/FragmentManager(1078):
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b2e06a08 G.ED.... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #1020317 android:id/split_action_bar} 05-06 03:54:32.460:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(1078): Shutting down VM 05-06 03:54:32.460:
>   W/dalvikvm(1078): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0xb2b01ba8) 05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078): Process:
>   com.vijay.mgit, PID: 1078 05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vijay.mgit/com.vijay.mgit.DisplayMessageActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c
>   (com.vijay.mgit:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{b2e07990 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 05-06 03:54:32.610:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 05-06 03:54:32.610:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 05-06 03:54:32.610:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-06 03:54:32.610:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1078): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.vijay.mgit:id/container) for
>   fragment PlaceholderFragment{b2e07990 #0 id=0x7f05003c} 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241) 05-06
>   03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
>   05-06 03:54:32.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1078):   ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is here

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vijay.mgit/com.vijay.mgit.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c

you are trying to start activity that have a view with some ID, and this ID is not found in any resource file.

to be more specific,
fragment PlaceholderFragment
at DisplayMessageActivity activity

Comment: I'm not able to understand what your are saying??

Comment: is this your package name? com.vijay.mgit, if yes, then you have runtime error in activity DisplayMessageActivity you ty to get a view by ID, this ID is not exist

Comment: fixed but also i cant able to run other programs whenever i,m trying to run programs on my emulator its showing the error unfortunately abc(emulator name) stopped working and displaying the above errors in logcat can you please tel me whats the problem with my emulator

Comment: thats th only thing i could see in the log, anyway you can try to create another emulator (virtual device) and try using it.